# Calculating the probability of winning a game with random numbers.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, game-theory

**The game**

This is a one player game. $n$ numbers are generated uniformly randomly from $0$ to $1$. These numbers are then written on $n$ tiles. One number per tile.  You may only look at one tile. You must then guess which tile has the largest number on it.

**Quick example**

The numbers $0.782$, $0.432$ and $0.882$ are generated randomly. Each wrote respectively on tiles $1, 2$ and $3$. You peek at tile $1$ and see $0.782$ and guess this as the largest tile. You are wrong. You loose.

**Solution for n=2**

Naturally in this simple case one peaks at any tile and if it greater than $\frac{1}{2} $ you guess that tile and if it is less you then guess the other tile. Let P denote the random variable that is the value on the tile you peak.

$\mathbb{P}[$You win ] = $\int_{0}^1 \mathbb{P}[$You win | $P = p ] f(p) 
  dp $

$f(p) =1 $ clearly. Hence splitting the integral over zero to one half and one half to one yields three quarters.

**My question**

General formula for the Probability of winning for a given $n>2$

I want to know when one should "stick". I know the expected value of the maximum of $k$ tiles is $\frac{k}{k+1}$. Should we only stick if our peaked tile is greater than that? Intuitively I feel like no. Is there some recursion we could use?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tile you choose has the number $p$, the probability that it is highest is $p^{n-1}$.  If you stick, the probability of winning is $p^{n-1}$.  If you switch, the probability of winning is $$\frac{1-p^{n-1}}{n-1}$$  This is the probability that you haven't chosen the highest, times the probability of choosing the highest, given that it is one of the other $n-1$.

You should stick when $$p^{n-1}>\frac{1-p^{n-1}}{n-1}$$

This simplifies to $$p>\frac1{\sqrt[n-1]n}$$

Comment: I think this is wrong. You need to work out your probability of winning if you switch. And compare it to that

Comment: @BearCakes100 Perhaps I misunderstand the game.  Don't you just say "yes" or "no"?

Comment: My reading is that after you look at tile $k$ you choose a tile number $j$ in $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ where $j$ can be $k$ or any of the others.  That might suggest sticking when $p^{n-1} > \frac1n$

Comment: I guess I misunderstood it then.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: This was great thank you :)